# JasperReport Multiple Databases in a single SQL Query and single Report

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

I am new with **JasperReports** (i'm using 5.0.0) and I have to develop a report in which the Oracle SQL Query is something like

```
SELECT A, B , C , (SELECT D , E FROM TABLEDATABASE2 WHERE D==A) FROM  TABLEDATABASE1
```

The subquery (`(SELECT D , E FROM TABLEDATABASE2 WHERE D==A)`) was formerly an Oracle function but now it has to be a proper query.

The Databases are in fact the same but with two diferent users who have their own tables.

I have try to do it with a subreport but I dont have any idea of how to make a nested query of two diferent datasources.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The executing user must have access to both tables and corresponding users.

You can use the GRANT statement to do so: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603

Regarding the query:

You must prefix the table names using their users in order to identify those objects:

```
SELECT       t1.A
            ,t1.B
            ,t1.C 
            ,t2.D
            ,t2.E
FROM        user1.TABLEDATABASE1 t1
  LEFT JOIN user2.TABLEDATABASE2 t2 ON t2.D = t1.A
```

Comment: The problem now, is that I am not the DBA so I can not grant privileges to the executing user so when I am launching  the report from my Java program I'm getting the "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" error .